# Loading JSON file error in Python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to learn how to read from a json file in Python and I am not sure how to interpret the error that I am getting I have posted my code below along with the error messages that I am getting. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
import json
filename = 'population.json'
with open(filename) as f:
    pop_data = json.load(f)
for pop_dict in pop_data:
    if pop_dict['Year'] == '2010':
        country_name = pop_dict['Country Name']
    population = pop_dict['Value']
    print(country_name + ":" + population)
```

**Error Msg----**

```
C:\Anaconda\python.exe "C:/PyCharm/Data Visual/Pop.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PyCharm/Data Visual/Pop.py", line 4, in <module>
    pop_data = json.load(f)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\json\__init__.py", line 299, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: What's in the `population.json` file? Is it maybe Unicode?

Comment: Look at the very first character of your JSON file, as the error message suggests. It must be a `[` or a `{`. If it's not, the parsing will fail. If the file looks OK in notepad, one thing I can think of is a BOM mark in a UTF-16 file.

Comment: Can you post couple of lines of 'population.json' file?. That will help narrow down problem, else there are multiple possibilities.

Comment: Use http://jsonlint.com/ to validate your json first

Comment: Country Name,Country Code,Year,Value
Arab World,ARB,1960,93485943
Arab World,ARB,1961,96058179
Arab World,ARB,1962,98728995
Arab World,ARB,1963,101496308
Arab World,ARB,1964,104359772
Arab World,ARB,1965,107318159
Arab World,ARB,1966,110379639
Arab World,ARB,1967,113543760

Comment: I posted a snip from my json file above. I am seeing that it is not properly formatted. Excuse my lack of knowledge here, but what is a BOM mark in a UTF-16? And are you saying that if I convert the json file to that it will fix my error?

Comment: It's ^^ totally not a JSON file, but it's likely a valid CSV file.

Comment: I figured out what I needed to do to get an actual json file. Thanks for the help everyone